# javascript noob... document write

Tags: javascript, navigation

I'm trying to use Javascript to load more links in [my nav bar](http://lelleny.co.uk/home).

This is what I tried; I just wanted one link in my nav to load more beneath it.

```
<a href="" onclick="show()"/>collections</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show() {
   document.write("collection 1 <br /> collection 2 <br /> etc... <br />");
}
</script>
```

Can anybody suggest a relevant tutorial or give me a hint?

Comment: Good source to learn JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: it doesn't work :) the link simply flashes up a new page with the word i originally wanted placing within the nav

Answer (score 5, accepted):

document.write should really only be used while the document is loading.  Calling it after the document is loaded will clear the current document and write some new content.  To add new content to the page, you would need to create new DOM objects and add them to the page or modify existing DOM objects.

Here's a small example of modifying the page you can see in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zVS39/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show()">collections</a>
<span id="moreText"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
function show() {
    var o = document.getElementById("moreText");
    o.innerHTML = "<br>collection 1 <br /> collection 2 <br /> etc... <br />";
}
```

Comment: ah perfect works grand thanks!

one question, how would one go about styling the individual links contained within the innerHTML in css?

i'm having trouble getting the links to to have any styles at all, they seem to have a mind of their own now :) and hovering over one is changing all of them...

the innerHTML isn't placed within the <span id="moreText"> is it?

thanks again, really appreciate it

http://www.lelleny.co.uk/home

Comment: Yes, it is all placed in the moreText span.  To style it individually, just add your own HTML tags or CSS classes to the HTML that you add.  You can then control the style just like any other part of your HTML page with CSS.  Put in spans with class IDs or any other HTML tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use innerHTML, or if you want to something more complex you could append a new element, for example:

HTML

```
<a href="" onclick="show()">collections</a>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function show() {
var hidden= document.getElementById("hidden"),
    newElem = document.createElement("div");

newElem.innerHTML = "<br>collection 1 <br /> collection 2 <br /> etc... <br />";
newElem.style.color = "red";
hidden.appendChild(newElem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Creating and modifying HTML](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-and-modifying-html/) from the WSC

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what your problem is.

But this is wrong:

```
<a href="" onclick="show()"/>collections</a>
```

You have made your `a` self-closing, so "collections" isn't part of the link and `</a>` is orphaned/invalid. Thus your function isn't going to fire when you click on "collections".

Write:

```
<a href="" onclick="show()">collections</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the innerHTML feature.

```
document.getElementById('someelement').innerHTML = "collection 1</br>collection2 ...";
```

So your HTML would look like:

```
<div id = "nav"></div>
<div id = "someelement></div>
```

So that text you wanna insert underneath your navigation will pop up in "somelement". You can also modify the css to do a show/hide type technique.