# How to make a simple web page displaying Bing Translator API results?

Tags: javascript, html, bing, bing-api

I want to use Bing Translator API to automatically translate some text in a page.

So, I'm using this code with my APP ID filled:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var Translate={
  baseUrl:"http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/",
  appId:"MY_APP_ID_HERE",
  translate:function(text,from,to,callback){
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src =this.baseUrl+"/Translate";
  s.src +="?oncomplete="+callback; 
  s.src +="&appId="+this.appId;
  s.src +="&from" + from ;
  s.src += "&to=" + to ;
  s.src += "&text=" + text; 
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
 }
}
var mycallback=function(result){alert(result)};
Translate.translate("Hello World","en","es","mycallback");
</script>
```

It works fine, displaying the result in an alert box.

My question : how to display the result on the page instead of in alert box ?
Kind of document.write, I guess...

Thanks for your help,

E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not related to Bing API, it is more of a JavaScript question, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637814/javascript-noob-document-write) for example on how to use innerHtml.