# Replacing a string of code in html in JS

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++

I'm new here and this is my first issue I've put up. This literally might be so easy for some of you it's not even funny. I need to replace and/or erase a string for this to fit. I've tried cutting out multiple lines near the end but I can't seem to get it to work for me. ALSO I'm using notepad++

Original string:

```js
var num1;
var num2;
var answer;
num1 = prompt("Enter a number ");
num2 = prompt("Enter a number ");
document.write("You entered " + num1 + " and " + num2);
document.write("<br>");
answer = prompt("Enter the sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2);
document.write("You entered " + answer);
document.write("<br>");
num1 = parseInt(num1);
num2 = parseInt(num2);
var sum = num1 + num2;
document.write("The sum is " + sum);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

String that I need to insert:

```js
if (answer == sum) {
  document.write("That is correct!");
} else {
  document.write("That is not correct. The correct answer is " + sum);
}
```

Comment: what happens when you copy the `string that you need to insert` above the closing `script` tag?

Comment: Let me try it, I'll put it right above, document.write("The sume is " + sum);

Comment: It behaves the same as it does with out the string I need to add. It doesn't say whether I did the addition right or wrong.

Comment: You can check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt24c29n/)

Comment: Odd, I literally don't know why mine don't work. Even when I edited mine to look like yours in firefox it still don't give me the results I want. Let me try to go through my code more clearly.

Comment: The difference between your code and @Rajesh 's fiddle seems to be that there is no semicolon after `var sum = num1 + num2`. On the other hand, at the bottom of the fiddle there is this message: `document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle environment and might break your fiddle.` So what does the fiddle do instead?

Comment: I took the condition of comparing `sum` and `answer` and replaced it with final document.write. Logic is not to write and replace string. Compute and then write correct value once

Comment: Related question: [javascript noob… document write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637814/javascript-noob-document-write)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `<span>` element to house the completion message:

```
<span id="answerMessage"></span>
```

Then you can apply the message that that span by:

```
document.getElementById("answerMessage").innerHTML = "Correct!";
```

That way there's no erasing or printing required for this message.

**Edit**

If your application is designed to look like a command based system with a fully printed history then ignore this solution. I provided this because that wasn't obvious in your question.

Comment: I think my problem is asking for a fully printed history but for right now it's asking me to add the listed string and get it to work. Literally for the 2nd problem I have to add that and it asks me to test it several times.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num1;
var num2;
var answer;
num1 = prompt("Enter a number ");
num2 = prompt("Enter a number ");
document.write("You entered " + num1 + " and " + num2);
document.write("<br>");
answer = prompt("Enter the sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2);
document.write("You entered " + answer);
document.write("<br>");
num1 = parseInt(num1);
num2 = parseInt(num2);
var sum = num1 + num2;
if (answer == sum) {
  document.write("That is correct!");
} else {
  document.write("That is not correct. The correct answer is " + sum);
}
document.write("The sum is " + sum);
```

Something like this should work

Comment: If I may ask, what were you using to run this string? Because if it's working for you in something other than notepad++ It's not for me =/

Comment: I used JSFiddle, copy the code snippet in JS section and run it clicking on the Run icon in the top left corner

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eba2uwgp/#&togetherjs=GhNKyuuf6c or click link

Comment: I don't know if you can open this, but this is what I get.

Comment: but I tested my code in JSFiddle and it works

Comment: Fair enough, I kinda gave up on this whole issue. I just think something is faulty on my end because I've even copied and pasted what some people have done into notepad++ and gotten the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This works here (in Firefox):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var num1;
      var num2;
      var answer;
      num1 = prompt("Enter a number ");
      num2 = prompt("Enter a number ");
      document.write("You entered " + num1 + " and " + num2);
      document.write("<br>");
      answer = prompt("Enter the sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2);
      document.write("You entered " + answer);
      document.write("<br>");
      num1 = parseInt(num1);
      num2 = parseInt(num2);
      var sum = num1 + num2;
      document.write("The sum is " + sum);
      document.write("<br>");
      if (answer == sum) {
        document.write("That is correct!");
      } else {
        document.write("That is not correct. The correct answer is " + sum);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```